# how to control multiple window open using java script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

In my application, we have the option of hitting the url and able to view the application in separate window.open dialog box. So that, my application looks like a individual window and we can start working on that.

How to do it :
Entering the url in the browser and clicking the enter button, then a new window.open dialog box will appear.

Issue :

Whenever i'm copying the url from that old tab and pasting it in the next tab, then browser allows to open the 2nd window.open dialog box, so that my application starts working as two separate dialog boxes.. I want to restrict this operation in my code.

I have restricted the same tab, multiple enter option, but i can't control the mulitple tab copy paste operations..

Note : 
During copy paste operation, i have implemented the session concept and that works fine as expected.

But, If a user tries to copy paste the login url and starts using the application, then my application allows the same user to login ... ( Because in each tab, the browser can use the same session id. )

Please help to restrict the multiple window.open feature in separate tabs.

Thanks in advance..

[image]

this my snippet:

```
var named_wnd = {};
var agt_value = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var broswerVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
var broswerVersion_nav = ((agt_value.indexOf('mozilla') != -1) && (agt_value.indexOf('spoofer') == -1) && (agt_value.indexOf('compatible') == -1) && (agt_value.indexOf('opera') == -1) && (agt_value.indexOf('webtv') == -1) && (agt_value.indexOf('hotjava') == -1));
var broswerVersion_v1 = (broswerVersion_nav && (broswerVersion == 6));
var broswerVersion_v6up = (broswerVersion_nav && (broswerVersion >= 6));
var id = 'myWin';

function BaseWNDURL(thisurl) {

    var named_wnd_Width = 810;
    var named_wnd_Height = 610;

    attr = 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,' +
        'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=' + named_wnd_Width + ',height=' + named_wnd_Height + ',' +
        'screenX=' + (screen.width - named_wnd_Width) / 2 + ',screenY=' + (screen.height - named_wnd_Height) / 2;

    if ((broswerVersion_v1 || broswerVersion_v6up)) {
        named_wnd[id] = window.open(thisurl, id, attr);

        if (broswerVersion_nav) {
            named_wnd[id].screenX = (screen.width - named_wnd_Width) / 2;
            named_wnd[id].screenY = (screen.height - named_wnd_Height) / 2;
        }
    } else {
        BaseWNDURL_OpenUP(thisurl);
    }
}

function BaseWNDURL_OpenUP(thisurl) {

    var named_wnd_Width = screen.width - 10;
    var named_wnd_Height = screen.height - 80;
    attr = 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes,menubar=no,' +
        'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=' + named_wnd_Width + ',height=' + named_wnd_Height + ',' +
        'screenX=' + (screen.width - named_wnd_Width) / 2 + ',screenY=' + (screen.height - named_wnd_Height) / 2;

    if (named_wnd[id]) {
        if (named_wnd[id].closed) {

            named_wnd[id] = window.open(thisurl, id, attr);
            if (broswerVersion_nav) {
                named_wnd[id].screenX = (screen.width - named_wnd_Width) / 2;
                named_wnd[id].screenY = (screen.height - named_wnd_Height) / 2;
            }
            named_wnd[id].focus();
        } else {
            named_wnd[id].focus();
        }
    } else {
        named_wnd[id] = window.open(thisurl, id, attr);

        if (broswerVersion_nav) {
            named_wnd[id].screenX = (screen.width - named_wnd_Width) / 2;
            named_wnd[id].screenY = (screen.height - named_wnd_Height) / 2;
        }

        named_wnd[id].focus();
    }
    named_wnd[id].focus();
}
```

Comment: its working in Internet explorer/fire fox. but in chrome not working as excepted